# WCF: Add Service Reference does not generate client proxy code

Tags: wcf, service-reference

I am trying to walk through this project sing Visual Studio 2010 Express

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/Text_to_speech_in_wp7.aspx?display=Print

to test Windows 7 phone text to speech.  When I add a reference to

```
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc
```

all seems to work.  However, I do not get client proxy code.  Reference.cs is empty and Visual Studio presents the following warnings and errors:

> Warning   1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
>   Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet' from assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2']/wsdl:portType[@name='LanguageService']  D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrackMe\TrackMe\Service References\MicrosoftTranslator\Reference.svcmap    1   1   TrackMe
>
> Warning   2   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
>   Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
>   XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2']/wsdl:portType[@name='LanguageService']
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService']    D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrackMe\TrackMe\Service References\MicrosoftTranslator\Reference.svcmap    1   1   TrackMe
>
> Warning   3   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
>   Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
>   XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService']
>   XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='SoapService']/wsdl:port[@name='BasicHttpBinding_LanguageService'] D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrackMe\TrackMe\Service References\MicrosoftTranslator\Reference.svcmap    1   1   TrackMe
>
> Warning   4   Custom tool warning: No endpoints compatible with Silverlight 3 were found. The generated client class will not be usable unless endpoint information is provided via the constructor.  D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrackMe\TrackMe\Service References\MicrosoftTranslator\Reference.svcmap    1   1   TrackMe
>
> Warning   5   Custom tool warning: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrackMe\TrackMe\Service References\MicrosoftTranslator\Reference.svcmap    1   1   TrackMe
>
> Error 6   Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'MicrosoftTranslator'.  Please check other error and warning messages for details. D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrackMe\TrackMe\Service References\MicrosoftTranslator\Reference.svcmap    1   1   TrackMe

Unchecking 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies" does not help either.

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: What is your target framework? Is it one of the Client Profile editions?

Comment: That is a good question?  I do not know nor can I found out from the usual spot; project -> properties.  I am working with a project created using VS 2010 express template.

Comment: No such option under the Application tab of the project properties, if this is what you are refering to.

Comment: @e28Makaveli, if you have a Client Profile installed, [this](http://i.imgur.com/q6xhX.png) is where you would find it.

Comment: Was that snapshot taken using V•Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone?  Because on my version, I simply do not have an option to select Target Framework.

Comment: VS1010 Professional, actually.

Comment: Express does not seem to allow changing Target Framework.  Even when you create a new project, it does not tell you the Target Framework.

Comment: Do not know what I did but it seems to be working fine today.  I can generate my service proxy.

Comment: I had to restart Visual Studio 2010 once for it to work.

Comment: Restarting VS 2012 just fixed this issue for me as well.